# Is there a word that means something that is popular, but everybody acts as if it's unpopular?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice

For example, something everybody calls "underrated" but is actually quite famous.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it a shot. How about a person (or character) people **love to hate**? From Macmillan:

> **[love to hate](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/love-to-hate)**: used for saying that someone takes pleasure in disliking someone or something; e.g., "She’s the character that viewers **love to hate**."

So, everyone acts as if they hate this person -- Jane, say -- so much so that you would think Jane is extremely unpopular -- but so many people love to hate Jane that she is in fact not extremely unpopular, but extremely popular.